# Custom variable in OpenERP template

Tags: python, odoo, templating, openerp-7

I would need some kind of counter for displaying position of element in list.

e.g. in invoice I have entries and I'm iterating through it like this:

```
[[ repeatIn(o.invoice_line,'l') ]]
```

now, I'm displaying, name, price etc. like this

```
[[ l.name ]] [[l.quantity]]
```

but I need position in order as well? I tried to have

```
[[ repeatIn(o.invoice_line,'l') ]]
[[ counter = 1 ]]
```

and in iteration:

```
[[ counter ]] [[ l.name ]] [[l.quantity]]
[[ counter = counter + 1 ]]
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing right thing and if custom variables are even allowed in open erp template

Comment: I think, You want serial number in line like 1. price, quantity 2. price, quantity etc. If you want that than you can create a function which will work like your counter and you can also display number by given return value in that function.

Comment: Where should I add this function? Into report_sxw.py? I would like to avoid modifying core part of openerp and do it by extending it...is it somehow possible?

Comment: yes, in .py side write function that will return integer number. And if you don't want to write code than tags are also available for this. for example that will do like counter. What you want ? Tag or function ?

Comment: tag would be fine. I tried the code above, but nothing was printed out...

Answer (score 0):

There are two tags useful for printing sequence.

1. `<seq/>` and
2. `<seqReset/>`

First use reset the sequence using `<seqReset/>`

In report `.rml` file, At Column label after write `<seqReset/>` and in `repeatIn` use `<seq/>`

For example:

```
    <td>
      <para style="terp_tblheader_Details_Right"><b>Price</b><seqReset/></para>
    </td>
```

And

```
    <td>
        <para style="terp_default_9"><seq/> [[ format(line.name) ]] </para>
    </td>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is this possible if I work with Open Office Writer to edit OpenERP templates?